# Url.Content does apparently not expand dynamically generated string

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to dynamically generate image path's based on an external variable in a razor view. I've seen other questions like this, however they did not seem to address my particular problem. There seem to be an issue with the order in which razor resolves the resulting string. If I try to expand below string, razor does not seem to expand the path correctly

```
var THEME_IMAGE_PATH = "@Url.Content(string.Format("/~/Scripts/dhtmlx/codebase/{0}_imgs/", ViewData["THEME"]))";
```

If I put in the right absolute path myself

```
var THEME_IMAGE_PATH = "@Url.Content(string.Format("/Home/Scripts/dhtmlx/codebase/{0}_imgs/", ViewData["THEME"]))";
```

or fully static string with relative path

```
var THEME_IMAGE_PATH = "@Url.Content("/~/Scripts/dhtmlx/codebase/SkyBlue_imgs/")";
```

Everything works.

Is there something in my syntax that makes razor not expand the result of a dynamically generated string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it with the first / . Once I removed that it worked.